# Apple In-House enterprise distribuition and authentication

Tags: ios

I tried the Apple standard $99 Developer plan to distribuite apps ad hoc.
The pro is that only UDIDs present in the device list can install the app, but cons: I have the limit of 100 iPhone and the list can only be reset once a year.

My organization has about 100 employs and this limit stops me.

Anyone know how enterprise in-house distribuition ($299/y) authentication works without using an MDM serivice?
In the documentation there isn’t a limit for installation but everyone has the link of the app can install it without any limitation.

Is there a way to prevent this without set up an autentication service? If a user share the apps OTA link it will be public..

With the udid I didn’t have this problem.

Comment: There is no limit enforced, but the contract has a limit -- last time I checked it was 250 -- but check. The normal thing to do is to make it have to authenticate or work with VPN and firewalled servers if you don't want people to use it outside of the org.

Comment: The enterprise membership has no limit, but devices must be “ownedl  by the enterprise (or BYO devices used by employees etc)

Comment: I see that now -- I am pretty sure there was a limit in the early days.  Nice that it's gone now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you aren’t distributing the app via an MDM then you would typically do so via a web site that required some sort of authentication from the user so that you can verify that they are authorised to obtain the app.

There is nothing in the .ipa itself that limits where it can be installed.

You could also build authentication into your app so that the user required an account to use it, even if they were able to install it an unauthorised user wouldn’t be able to use it.